# Connection refused to docker host in bridge mode

Tags: docker

I need to connect to a service (mongodb) that runs on the docker host machine from within a container.

It's my understanding that normally, this could be accomplished by using the IP of the `bridge` network that's being created when installing docker.

```
$ ip addr show docker0
3: docker0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:6c:fe:1a:7c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:6cff:fefe:1a7c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The container runs in that bridge mode as well, however connecting to `172.17.0.1` doesn't work and I get a `connection refused` error when trying to connect to `172.17.0.1:27017` from within the container.

```
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "5c0d970d746769138db12d51fcd694fceafc8cf2a16edf142d1d860958afe3ac",
                    "EndpointID": "5474db3debff8029197dfc2723bf3af1262fa20d9a6d878e08db7976b578e5b2",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.3",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:03",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
```

When I switch to `host` mode, this works as expected when using localhost as the target address. But it doesn't in bridge mode with the `172` adresses... why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check the IP in the mongo config file, the IP with which you want to externally access the mongo server should ideally be mentioned in config file.

Comment: do you mean `bind_ip = 127.0.0.1` ? That's whats defined in the `/etc/mongod.conf` file anyway. Does that mean I need to add `172.17.0.1` to that?

Comment: Yes please change it to the Ip you want to connect which in your case is 172.17.0.1

Comment: Awesome! I added it to the list (because other services need to connect from `127.0.0.1` as well) and it works now even in bridge mode :-)